# Show hours and skill level per skills in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Essentially I'd like to see something like

Skill     Level Hours

Ruby  Adept 3,000

HTML  Adept 8,000

CSS   Adept 5,000

Javascript Intermediate 1,000

edit:
I think it's a useful metric.  Right now, people tend to use "years doing x".  Hours is just more specific.

I think it's a nicer way to express your competency than just listing skills and jobs.

Comment: Hours work with something != Experience with it. I can't tell if somebody with 20 years coding experience knows ssssss...stuff.

Comment: seems like a simple, optional feature request, I find it astonishing that I got 9 downvotes

Comment: Because measuring experience in hours is like measuring coding skill in lines of code written.

Answer (score 2):

How would you measure the hours experience? I remember reviewing a CV where the combined 'years' experience (which could be converted to hours) added up to over 330 years of experience.

I would also add that hours experience is indirectly related to skill levels, there is some correlation but the quality of the experience counts for a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen incompetent people spend weeks working away on some task that should have only taken a matter of hours had they only had the skills/knowledge in the first place.

If I were an employer, all I could infer from "hours spent using skill X" is that candidate Y is *probably* more competent at skill X, but also *possibly* even less competent than candidate Z, about whom I know nothing of hours per skill.

Answer (score 1):

What would hours of experience really tell you though besides being a rough guideline? An hour worth of experience might be more productive for you than me for example. Wouldn't a better guide for experience be the questions and answers the user has provided for the relevant tags / experiences that he/she has listed? As these don't only show experience, but knowledge and understanding as well.